# Regex - extract word from www.anything.com

Tags: regex

I am trying to use Regex to match a word within a www URL. In the event that the www does not exist, I would still like it to match on the '.com'. For example if the following text was present...

www.**anything**.com

**anything**.com

It would return "**anything**" as the result. In the event that the 'www' is not present, it could still get it from the word before '.com'. But if the 'www' is present, I would like it to look there first.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm confused and don't see where this was asked already.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Perl:

```
$ echo "www.anything.com
> anything.com" | perl -lane 'print $1 if /^(?:www\.)?([^.]+)\.com$/'
anything
anything
```

Comment: Thanks. However Perl is not compatible with my software that uses the Regex statements.

Comment: Specify how / where you are trying to use a regex.

Comment: False positives include `C:\Windows\System32\diskcopy.com`. On the other hand, `meta.stackoverflow.com` will not be matched.

Comment: Neither of those were specified as possible input strings. The user specifically states *In the event that the 'www' is not present, it could still get it from the word before '.com'* so by that criteria `C:\Windows\System32\diskcopy.com` should match and the user stated only `www` as the only lead clause, so `meta.stackoverflow.com` should not match.